# How to match single words AND combinations of words using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a users text input against a set of predefined keywords and phrases.

Example:

```
var keywordRegEx = /\b(nutrition|protein|muscle|muscle growth|muscle repair|muscle food|foods)\b/ig;

var user_input = "What are the best foods for muscle growth and muscle repair";
var matches = user_input.match(keywordRegEx);

console.log(matches); 
//["foods", "muscle", "muscle"]
```

But what I want to see in the console is:

```
//["foods", "muscle", "muscle growth", "muscle repair"]
```

Is there any way to match against single whole words AND combinations including those whole words using regex?

*Note that if I remove "muscle" from the the list of predefined keywords and phrases I get the following:

```
var keywordRegEx = /\b(nutrition|protein|muscle growth|muscle repair|muscle food|foods)\b/ig;

var user_input = "What are the best foods for muscle growth and muscle repair";
var matches = user_input.match(keywordRegEx);

console.log(matches);
//["foods", "muscle growth", "muscle repair"]
```

But I need to be able to match single words by themselves..

I'm fairly lost when it comes to regex so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, just add the single words in the regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To catch single words and their combinations you can use two RegExps and combine them into single array. Such solution is easier to read and probably faster than a single RegExp:

```js
var keywordRegEx = /nutrition|protein|foods|muscle/g;
var keywordPairsRegEx = /muscle growth|muscle repair|muscle food/g;

var user_input = "What are the best foods for muscle growth and muscle repair";
var matches = user_input.match(keywordRegEx) //first regex
            .concat(user_input.match(keywordPairsRegEx)) //second regex
            .filter(( item, index, inputArray ) => { //remove duplicates
              return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
            });

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot @Oskar

Answer (score 2):

You were so close. Just add the single words later. In this case add `muscle` at the end of your regex.

Note: I've also changed the input string (added `muscle`) just to show that the regex now grabs single and multiple words.

```js
const keywordRegEx = /(nutrition|protein|muscle growth|muscle repair|muscle food|foods|muscle)/g;

var user_input = "What are the muscle best foods for muscle growth and muscle repair";
var matches = user_input.match(keywordRegEx);

console.log(matches);
```

Play with it here: https://regex101.com/r/Ge5Kry/1

Comment: You forgot to mention that you've changed the input string

Comment: @Oskar true! just to show that the regex now also grabs single and not single words which it didn't before. Will update the answer with that info!